# shared domain with scala.js, how?

Tags: scala.js

Probably a basic question, but I'm confused with the various documentations and examples around [scala.js](https://www.scala-js.org/).

I have a domain model I would like to share between scala and scala.js, let's say:

```
class Estimator(val nickname: String)
```

... and of course I would like to send objects between the web-client (scala.js with angular via angulate) and the server (scala with spring-mvc on spring-boot).

**Should the class extends *js.Object*? And be annotated with *@ScalaJSDefined* (not yet deprecated in v0.6.15)?**

- If yes, it would be an unwanted dependency that comes also in the server part. Neither *@scalaJSDefined* nor *js.Object* are in the dummy *scalajs-stubs*. Or am I missing something?
- If no, how to pass them through $http.post which expects a *js.Any*? I also get some *TypeError* at other places. Should I picke/unpickle everywhere or is there an automatic way?

EDIT 2017-03-30:

Actually this relates to [Angulate](https://github.com/jokade/scalajs-angulate), the facade for AngularJS I choose. For 2 features (communications to an http server and displaying model fields in html), the domain classes have to be Javascript classes. In Angulate's example, the domain model is duplicated.

There are also (and sadly) no plan to include `js.Object` in *scalajs-stubs* to overcome this problem. Details in https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/2564 . Perhaps `js.Object` doesn't hurt so much on the jvm...

**So, what web frameworks and facade for scala.js does / doesn't nicely support shared domain?** Not angulate1, probably Udash, perhaps react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Caveat: I don't know Angulate, which might affect some of this. Speaking generally, though...)

No, those shared objects shouldn't derive from `js.Object` or use `@ScalaJSDefined` -- those are only for objects that are designed to interface with JavaScript itself, and it doesn't sound like that's what you have in mind. Objects that are just for Scala don't need them.

But yes -- in general, you're usually going to need to pickle the communications in one way or another. Which pickling library you use is up to you (there are several), but remember that the communication is simply a stream of bytes -- you have to tell the system how to serialize and deserialize between your domain objects and those bytes.

There isn't anything automatic in Scala.js per se -- that's just a language, and doesn't dictate your library choices. You *can* use implicits to make the pickling semi-automatic, but I recommend being a bit careful with that. I don't see anything obvious in the Angulate docs that indicate that it does the pickling automatically.

Comment: With Angular a little bit of javascript is use, such as to pick a field (example: pick _estimator.nickname_ as the model&field of an <input>). Without `@ScalaJSDefined` the fields have special names, for example _nickname$1_.

Comment: **pickle:** AngularJS pickles per default with a JSON encoding. It is handled by spring-boot, so everything good there. [Angulate](https://github.com/jokade/scalajs-angulate), the AngularJS facade I choose, works with js.Any. There are the plain Scala objects currently not supported.

Comment: Hi @justin-du-coeur, what web framework(s) do you use for scala.js? And do you sometimes need to derives from `js.Object` with it?

Comment: I don't use an established framework -- Querki predates essentially all of the Scala.js framework facades, so I rolled my own framework out of jQuery, Scalatags, Scala.Rx and other bits and pieces.  That works fairly well, but I wouldn't recommend that route currently: it's a lot of effort.

Comment: As for deriving from `js.Object`, sure -- but the thing is, most frameworks don't use the same object for *data* and *display*.  Display objects usually need to derive from `js.Object` at some level, but the client/server data objects rarely do, at least in most frameworks.  But again, I don't know Angular...